# \usepackage{caption} breaks references to tables

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, listings, captions

I'm formatting the listings captions as follows:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}
```

However, I realized that just writting `\usepackage{caption}` breaks references to tables, causing warnings like:

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `table:swtp' on page 13 undefined on input line 44.
```

and LaTeX writes "Table. ??" in the generated document.

This an example that gives me the problem:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}

See the Table ~\ref{table:example}

\begin{table}[htdp] 
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | c | c |}
    \hline
    A & B  \\ \hline
    1 & 2 \\ 
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{my cap}
\end{center}
  \label{table:example}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete MWE that shows your problem. Do you compile twice?

Comment: If you don't know what a MWE is you can read it here: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: You forgot to mention the warning `Package caption Warning: \label without proper \caption on input line 19.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.` your example causes. When taking a look at the caption package doc you'll see that's not a bug, it's a feature ;-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With

```
\begin{table}[htdp] 
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | c | c |}
    \hline
    A & B  \\ \hline
    1 & 2 \\ 
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{my cap}
\end{center}
  \label{table:example}
\end{table}
```

the label is defined when the `center` environment has already been closed and the object which the reference should be attached to has been forgotten.

Never use the `center` environment inside `figure` or `table`:

```
\begin{table}[htbp] 
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{ | c | c |}
    \hline
    A & B  \\ \hline
    1 & 2 \\ 
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{my cap}\label{table:example}
\end{table}
```

Notice also that `d` is not among the possible float specifiers and probably you were meaning `b` (bottom).

Answer (score 12):

Had kind of the same Error, but for me the solution was, putting the `\label` after the `\caption` command (which makes kind of sense...)

Comment: The `\label` *is* after the `\caption` command in the question so this is likely to be the answer. Please check before posting...

Comment: I know, but I came here with the same error, but for me it was the wrongly placed '\label', I just want other people coming here lead into the right direction!

Comment: Thanks @Marcel. I think your answer is relevant. I ended up here looking for an answer to the question and this worked.